# requirejs Load timeout path for debugging

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have an error when I load datatables js.

```
Load timeout for modules: datatables
```

It is possible I have some wrong configuration (path). 
How can I check where requirejs expects file ? Can I get path from module in requirejs ?

I don't see any fail load file in Chrome console.

```
"datatables": "DataTables/DataTables-1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min",
"datatables.net": "DataTables/DataTables-1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put two different module names pointing to the same file path in your `paths` configuration, then that's not going to work: RequireJS will error out.

If you want two module names to resolve to the same file, what you should do is use `map` to perform the mapping and leave only one module in `paths`, like:

```
paths: {
  "datatables.net": "DataTables/DataTables-1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min",
},
map: {
  "*": {
    datatables: "datatables.net",
  },
}
```

The `map` setting makes it so that when any module (`"*"`) makes a request for the module named `datatables` it receives the module named `datatables.net` instead.